# ios usaepay magstripe credit card data, send for processing

Tags: ios, credit-card, magnetic-cards, usaepay

In my application I use online payment, for that i used PaySabar device (audio jack device) which reads magstrip data on credit card swipe.

I got credit data in encrypted format, all track1, track2 data are correct and perfect, but how to i send that data to USAePAY server. Please help.

Comment: So I'm trying to do the exact same thing but I'm super confused as to what direction to take so that the swiped data can be passed to USAePay. Did you ever figure this out out? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe USAePay requires the encrypted data to be:

1. Encrypted with their public key
2. Formatted in a specific manner
3. Passed in magstripe or credit card number field

Because you are using their PaySaber hardware, see below for step 3.

[USAePay Wiki - End To End Encryption:](http://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/endtoendencryption)

> If you are using idynamo library, here is what you need to do:
>
> `NSString *responseString = [mtSCRALib getResponseData];` 
> `NSData *responseData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`
> `NSString *encodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"enc://%@", [^] [responseData base64Encoding]];`
>
> and then send encodedString to the gateway as MagStripe.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to integrate your application with one of their transaction interfaces.  You will also need a developer account for testing transaction responses.

They have a wide array of different integration solutions and source code examples to use, including an iOS library.

http://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/Support

Comment: I have gone through this could you help me more to integrate this because i haven't found any support for that in ios.

Comment: Did you try implementing the iOS Library listed here:http://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/ios

Comment: Yes i done it this task successfully. First of all i create my server in .net and that server is send to all request to usaepay server and i send all information to my server and that is send to usaepay